# ecryptfs: What would happen if we entered the wrong passphrase and continued like that? Can we prevent encryptfs from accepting a wrong passphrase?

Tags: encryption, linux, digital-signature, filesystems

Using *ecryptfs*, a fine file-system encryption mechanism on Linux.

After the filesystem is setup with *ecryptfs* (*ecryptfs* is an overlay of the actual filesystem, like `ext4`. Files and directories name and content are encrypted ; names are ASCII-converted so that the FS has no issue handling them), it can be mounted using a passphrase.

To use (mount) the FS, *ecryptfs* accepts a passphrase, and compares its signature  with a signature stored initially (in `~/.ecryptfs/sig-cache.txt`).

If the signatures don't match, *ecryptfs* then shows a warning message

> WARNING: Based on the contents of [/.../.ecryptfs/sig-cache.txt], it looks like you have never mounted with this key before. **This could mean that you have typed your
> passphrase wrong**.
>
> Would you like to proceed with the mount (**yes/no**)? :

I never tried the *yes* option out of fear of the potential damage it could cause to the files.

Two questions

1. What would actually happen to the files & dirs if the user goes along with the "yes" option?
2. Is there a way / mount option / setup in order to prevent *ecryptfs* from accepting a wrong (different sig actually) passphrase and just abort, instead of offering the user a way to go along with a wrong key?  (I could modify the source code to do that, but I'd have to change it each time a new version is released ; not so tempting!)